# Open a new application and pass mouse events in MSVC++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, message-queue, hwnd

I have an application (a c++ console app) which I'd like to programmatically open a new window, launch another application (a flash projector) in it, and pass mouse events from the parent to the child.

I've tried launching the two applications independently and using SendInput to control the global mouse position but this is a little crude. The position of the receiving window becomes critical!

Ideally, I'd create a new window so I have the HWND and send windows messages straight to that.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I didnt bother opening a child window, just searched for an existing app.

Just used

```
HWND h = FindWindow("ShockwaveFlash", NULL);
// ...
SendMessage( h, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, data );
```